# How to make elements fit AutoLayout in Xcode IB?

Tags: ios, autolayout, interface-builder, ios-autolayout

I set some constrains to several elements in Interface Builder. Is there any automatic way to force them fit those constrains?

[image: Example]

Comment: So when you run the app it works, you just want it to look right in the storyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the object which you need to be fixed and use "Update Frames" or "Update Constraints" as per your need.Check attached screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaking, you are asking for this feature:

after selecting your view, open "Resolve Auto Layout Issues" (the option with triangle icon):

[image]

and select "Update Constraints":

[image]

and that's it!

note that if you select "Update Frames", the view's frame should back to its previous status.